# Stretch traffy around a corner

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, soft-body

To learn more about Blender Physics, I've developed a scenario that encompasses what I want to be able to achieve.

**GOAL**

Something like rubbery taffy is stretched out from a post, around a sharp corner, then rolled onto a stick, overlapping itself.

The taffy will not have a consistent cross section, it is randomly irregular.

Some important physics details:

1. When the taffy interacts with the sharp corner, it flattens a bit like it would in real life. Otherwise maintains volume.
2. When the taffy is rolled onto the stick, it self-collides and doesn't clip.
3. The taffy is under tension (stretched out); I might animate the stick moving around, so tension would vary.
4. Gravity should act on the whole suspended portion to cause droop.

From other videos, it seems baking + tweaking is common, but I would prefer a pure simulation approach (no intervention), even if it's really slow.

**PROGRESS**

So far I've tried to use cloth physics, but there's no volume preservation, and it clips through the corners of the block.

[image]

I'm using 2.79, but if 2.8 is better for this, I can switch.

Any direction or reference to good resources would be appreciated. I have uploaded my file below.

[image]

Comment: Could you share the blend file?

Comment: @MikeGO - What file uploader would you recommend?

Comment: @MikeGO - I have uploaded the file.

Comment: For preserving volume you can add internal structure to the mesh as described in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/130365/29586 but I think the stretching will be beyond the capabilities of the Soft Body simulation - the stretching forces will be far too extreme to result in a stable simulation.