# How do I stop the middle of a soft body from drooping?

Tags: soft-body

I am currently making a simulation in which a jelly cube will drop. the desired effect is for the cube to jiggle a lot on impact but for it to slowly come back to the shape of a cube. in general terms, how do I get a soft body to be extremely sensitive to collisions but to return to its original shape when undisturbed? 
[image: Here is the drooping in the center of the object]

Comment: there might be some clue here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117463/soft-body-preserve-volume-when-deformed

Comment: The parameter you want to set is the stiffness, also make edges sensitive to collision will help.